# $('body').html() duplicate string in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to copy the  element in JQuery, and then concat it to my DIV.

Im trying to do it like that :

```
var bodyHtml = $('body').html();
var myDIV = '<div class="myDIV"></div>';
 $('body').html( bodyHtml+ myDIV );
```

but when Im trying it, somehow it inject the "myDIV" div, twice.

any thoughts why ?

Comment: Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/r9HHs/. btw you could just do `$('body').append(myDIV );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method **[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** instead.

```
$('body').append('<div class="myDIV"></div>');
```